# Hibernate Batch processing

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, batch-processing

So I am trying to configure Hibernate for batch processing purposes. I have built a sample application and configured according to Hibernates docs.

But after configuring Hibernate to log out the SQL, it looks like it is not performing a batch insert at all but merely individual inserts. Am I reading this log wrong?

So I have the following properties configured in my Spring Boot app.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Here is my very basic Batch Writer..

`@Transactional
public class BatchWriter {`

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

private int batchSize;

public BatchWriter(EntityManager entityManager, int batchSize) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
}

public void writeBatchOfCustomers(int numOf) {
    for(long i = 0; i <= numOf; i++) {
        Customer customer = new Customer(i);
        entityManager.persist(customer);

        if ( i % batchSize == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now I am running this to insert 20 Customers for example and in the hibernate log I am seeing the following 20 times:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    customer
    (first_name, last_name, id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?)
```

What am I missing here?

It is currently using Spring Boot auto configuration with H2 database. I will however be looking to use it with Spring Batch and an Oracle db eventually, which will be inserting around 30k objects with about 35 attributes.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using a plain SessioNFactory when you are configuring JPA? You should be using an `EntityManager` not a `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Because that code is near enough copied off the hibernate docs, it is just throw away. I didn't see an impact?

Comment: Again you are configuring JPA but are using a plain `SessionFactory`. You are configuring X, but are using Y. Why do you think configuring X will influence Y. As stated use an `EntityManager` (just inject it into your writer) and annotate the class with `@Transactional`. Remove any Hibernate configuration you have and let Spring Boot configure JPA for you.

Comment: I was using the original snippet. But i was unwrapping the session from the configured JPA EntityManagerFactory in my config. So although pointless, it wasn't affecting the outcome. Anyway, i've changed it to use JPA.

Comment: Why are you configuring JPA yourself that basically renders anything in the `application.properties` pointless.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Spring is auto wiring everything. I was merely using a snippet of code that is programmed to SessionFactory, so I took simply unwrapped the underlying session factory from JPA and used it?

Comment: You state in your comment you use the configured entitymanagerfactory. Which makes me think you are configuring a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` yourself.

Comment: No I am just autowiring the EntityManagerFactory that spring boot auto configures and unwrapping the underlying implementation because I know it's hibernate and the code snippet I was using, uses hibernate specifically. Anyway, this doesn't really address the question which was about hibernate logging of batch processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that the hibernate SQL logging is rather misleading (in my opinion).

My configuration was in fact batch processing.

I added a logger with level DEBUG for this class:

`org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch`

as currently named in Hibernate version 5.0.12. (Think it is named something else previously).

In this class you can see the it is in fact batch processing.